# Cylindrical billboarding around an arbitrary axis in geometry shader

Tags: mathematics, shaders, matrix, billboarding

I found an answer on this site relating to this question already, but it doesn't seem applicable in the context of my project.

Basically I'd like to create a method which fits this signature:

```
float3x3 AxisBillboard(float3 source, float3 target, float3 axis)
```

That is to say, when given a source point (i.e an object's position in world space), a target (camera position in world space), and an axis (the object's up vector, which is not necessarily the global y axis), it produces a 3x3 rotation matrix by which I can multiply the vertices of my point so that it's properly rotated.

I've found many solutions and tutorials online which work nicely assuming I only want to rotate around the y axis.

For example, here's a solution which billboards around the global y axis:

```
float3 dir = normalize(target - source);
    
float angleY = atan2(dir.x, dir.z);
c = cos(angleY);
s = sin(angleY);
    
float3x3 rotYMatrix;
rotYMatrix[0].xyz = float3(c, 0, s);
rotYMatrix[1].xyz = float3(0, 1, 0);
rotYMatrix[2].xyz = float3(-s, 0, c);
```

For context, I'm working on a grass shader, and each individual blade of grass should be billboarded to face the camera while remaining aligned with the normal of the terrain.

edit:

Thanks to @DMGregory I'm using his matrix method in the following way:

```
float3 viewDir = normalize(vertexPosition); // camera is at (0, 0, 0)
float3x3 billboardMatrix = transpose(AxisBillboard(worldUp, viewDir));
float3 worldPosition = vertexPosition + mul(billboardMatrix, localPosition);
```

This works correctly when grass is rotated to align with world space. In other rotations, grass is still billboarding 'correctly' around its local y axis but also has another rotation applied. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as hard as it might seem.

We can simplify two of your arguments to one:

```
float3 viewDirection = target - source;
```

Then our strategy will be to cross the vertical axis and view direction to get a vector perpendicular to both (the right/sideways direction).

Next, we cross this with our vertical axis to complete the basis.

A rotation matrix is just a unit vector in each basis direction, so we can assign our vectors directly to the rows/columns of our matrix.

```
float3x3 AxisBillboard(float3 upAxis, float3 viewDirection) {
    float3 rightAxis = normalize(cross(upAxis, viewDirection));
    float3 forwardAxis = cross(rightAxis, upAxis);

    float3x3 result;
    result[0].xyz = rightAxis;
    result[1].xyz = upAxis;
    result[2].xyz = forwardAxis;

    return transpose(result);
}
```

Comment: So this sort of works, the grass is billboarding around its local y axis. However, only the grass which is oriented with y-up globally looks correct. Grass which has its local up in other directions has other unwanted rotations applied as well, though the billboarding is 'correct.' I'll attach an image and some more code to my original post to illustrate, if you have any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not able to reproduce the issue you're seeing when I place this code in my own shader. I'm getting correct billboarding around any arbitrary up axis. It's possible the error might be coming from somewhere else.